# how can I exlude all files except one in Atomiq using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use the [Atomiq](http://www.getatomiq.com/) tool to check only **one** file for duplicate code. However there is only a regex exclusion option.

I've tried using .*(?!filename) to exclude all negative results which doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: and what is your filename..that filename should only contain the name of the file and its extention

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex to get your result

> (.*)filename

Comment: This won't work. Since it's an exclusion I need to exclude **negative** results.